# Undefined control sequence \for loop

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmic

```
\begin{algorithm}[tb]

\scriptsize $\prod_m$: Manipulated Call Trace,
\scriptsize $\prod_n$: Natural Call Trace     \\
\scriptsize $\Delta_m$: Unaligned Call Trace in $\prod_m$,
\scriptsize $\Delta_n$: Unaligned Call Trace in $\prod_n$, \\
\scriptsize $f_{\prod}$: $\langle name,caller\ eip,parameter\ list\rangle$,
\scriptsize $f_{\Delta}$: $\langle name,parameter\ list\rangle$

\begin{algorithmic}[1]                   % enter the algorithmic environment
\caption{Differential Analysis on the API-Call Traces}
\label{algo:diff}
    $\Delta_m\leftarrow  \emptyset$,$\Delta_n \leftarrow  \emptyset$

\For{call $f_{\prod_m}$ in $\prod_m$}{
    \For{call $f_{\prod_n}$ in $\prod_m$}{
        \If {isAligned($f_{\prod_m}$,$f_{\prod_n}$)}{
         GOTO FIND\_ALIGNED
        }
    }
 $\Delta_m=\Delta_m \bigcup f_{\Delta_m}$
}
 $\Delta_n=\prod_n$
 FIND\_ALIGNED:
        $\Delta_n= \prod_m[0,index(f_{\prod_n})]$
        $\{f_{\Delta_i}\}$=Diff($\Delta_m$,$\Delta_n$)
    return $\{f_{\Delta_i}\}$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

showing error:
You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.
\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -\@m \p@ 
l.100

```
$\Delta_n=\prod_n$
```

I am using `algorithm2e` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\FOR` does not exist, did you mean `\For`? Notice that LaTeX commands are case sensitive.

Comment: welcome me to TeX SX! :p 

yeah I meant \For

I have edited the code! 
New issue:
You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.
\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -\@m \p@ 
l.100  $
        \Delta_n=\prod_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot combine the use of [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) and content from the [`algorithms` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) (which includes the `algorithmic` package/environment) or [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). It's *either* `algorithm2e` *or* something else.

By looking at your syntax, it seems you are favouring `algorithm2e`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[tb]
  \caption{Differential Analysis on the API-Call Traces}

  \LinesNotNumbered
  $\prod_m$: Manipulated Call Trace,
    $\prod_n$: Natural Call Trace\;
  $\Delta_m$: Unaligned Call Trace in $\prod_m$,
    $\Delta_n$: Unaligned Call Trace in $\prod_n$, \;
  $f_{\prod}$: $\langle$ name, caller eip, parameter list$\rangle$,
    $f_{\Delta}$: $\langle$ name, parameter list$\rangle$

  $\Delta_m\leftarrow  \emptyset$,$\Delta_n \leftarrow  \emptyset$

  \For{call $f_{\prod_m}$ in $\prod_m$}{
    \For{call $f_{\prod_n}$ in $\prod_m$}{
      \If{isAligned($f_{\prod_m}$, $f_{\prod_n}$)}{
      GOTO FIND\_ALIGNED
      }
    }
    $\Delta_m = \Delta_m \bigcup f_{\Delta_m}$\;
  }
  $\Delta_n = \prod_n$\;
  FIND\_ALIGNED:\;
  \Indp
    $\Delta_n = \prod_m[0, \mbox{index}(f_{\prod_n})]$\;
    $\{f_{\Delta_i}\}$ = Diff($\Delta_m$, $\Delta_n$)\;
    return $\{f_{\Delta_i}\}$\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

You'll have to sort out the line numbering and formatting of the caption, since they change depending on whether you use `algorithm2e` or something else. There are examples contained within the [`algorithm2e` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf).

Comment: Wow! thank you very much that worked! Yeah messed it up with the use of algorithm2e and content from the algorithms bundle (which includes the algorithmic package/environment) or algorithmicx